# Proving from "first principles" that $(f+g)' = f' + g'$

Tags: calculus

> Prove from ﬁrst principles that the derivative of the sum of two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is the sum of their derivatives.

I do not know how to approach this question. I have never dealt with first principle questions which involved a $g(x)$ so I am a bit confused how I would go about it in the first place.

Comment: Are you asking for a proof of the product rule by first principles? First principles just means using the definition of the derivative

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{f(x+h)+g(x+h)-(f(x)+g(x))}{h}=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} + \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$